# unable to ping but internet work fine

Tags: 14.04, ping

I have Ubuntu 14.04.05 Server which is running on HyperV server as a VM. I am unable to [image: ping] google or any public ip address but when I run apt-get update or any application install it connects & get it installed.

P.S: properly set dns ip address.

Comment: Is the HyperV server controlled by you?

Comment: Well, it could be that a firewall is blocking pings. Would explain why you can still use the internet but not ping.

Answer (score 2):

To ping an IP address, DNS is out of the picture so we can look at that later.

My standard approach to network connectivity is:

```
ping localhost

ping gateway IP

ping google.com
```

If something fails (e.g. google.com), to find out how far the packet got, type

```
traceroute google
```

Odd that apt-get works but a more reliable test would be to open a browser and go to some always up web site such as google.com.  Use lynx if nothing else is installed.

I've seen odd network behavior in VM environments.  Verify that network connectivity works (or doesn't) on other VM OS running on the same box.  I'm assuming by your question that the physical hardware belongs to you and that you have full administrator control over the Hypervisor and all of the operating systems running on it.

Rare but worth looking at is that ping is using a dead interface.  You can try

```
ping -I interface google.com
```

Or you could be invoking a bogus version of ping.  You should be calling /bin/ping

```
which ping
```

Another possibility is that ICMP is being blocked somewhere.  To prove this, try to ssh onto any known running server.  Even if you get a connection refused you'll know you at least reached the device.